# Is it possible to init all Taghelpers before Processing it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have one TagHelper which is creating a context in it's `Init` method:

```
public class TabContext
{
    public bool HasExplicitActiveItem { get; set; }
    public bool HasActiveItem { get; set; }
}
```

In the children Taghelper, I am trying to set `HasExplicitActiveItem` if this taghelper has an Html Attribute (`bool IsActive`) set to `true`:

```
public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
{
    //...
    if (IsActive)
    {
        _tabContext.HasExplicitActiveItem = true;
    }
}
```

Now, when the taghelpers are initialized, and `HasExplicitActiveItem` is not true, I want to set the `IsActive` state from the first child taghelper:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    //...
    if (_tabContext.HasActiveItem)
    {
        IsActive = false;
    }
    else if (!_tabContext.HasExplicitActiveItem)
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }
    if (IsActive)
    {
        _tabContext.HasActiveItem = true;
    }
    //...
}
```

However, this does not work, because every child tag helper is initialized and processed before the next child tag helper is initialized.

To call them I use `await output.GetChildContentAsync()` from the parent tag-helper.

So is it possible to first initialize all (direct) children, and then process it? If not, is there a way to prescan the properties of the children?

---

In doubt, I have an XY Problem, the desired markup is this:

```
<tab>
    <tab-pane />
    <tab-pane />
    <tab-pane is-active="true" />
    <tab-pane />
</tab>
```

If the `is-active` is not set, I want to set `is-active` on the first `tab-pane`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by not outputting anything from the children.

I have mapped any children data into an Item Context:

```
public class TabPaneContext
{
    public IHtmlContent Content { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The main Context only gets a List of the Item Context:

```
public class TabContext
{
    public IList<TabPaneContext> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The children Taghelper saves the actualy content into the Item Context:

```
public class TabPaneTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private TabContext _tabContext;
    private TabPaneContext _tabPaneContext = new TabPaneContext();

    public string Id
    {
        get => _tabPaneContext.Id;
        set => _tabPaneContext.Id = value;
    }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => _tabPaneContext.IsActive;
        set => _tabPaneContext.IsActive = value;
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get => _tabPaneContext.Title;
        set => _tabPaneContext.Title = value;
    }

    public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        _tabContext = context.Items[typeof(TabContext)];
        _tabContext.Items.Add(_tabPaneContext);
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        _tabPaneContext.Content = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
        output.SuppressOutput();
    }
```

The actualy generation of the output is done by the main taghelper by iterating over the Items.

Not sure how efficient it is, but it is working. Still feels a bit dirty.